# Count number of occurrences

Tags: python

I have the following list of numbers:

```
l = [2L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 14L, 11L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 14L, ...]
```

How would I find out the number of occurrences of a number (e.g., `2`) or of multiple numbers (e.g., `2` or `5` or `7`)?

The way I was going to do it was with a `for` loop, but I'm sure there's a more efficient way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`collections.Counter` makes a dictionary that maps values to the number of times they occur:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = [2L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 14L, 11L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 14L]
>>> c = Counter(l)
>>> c
    Counter({14L: 6, 2L: 5, 11L: 3})
>>> c[14L]
    6
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> l.count(2)
5
```

Simple as pie. If you have a list of numbers for which you would like to find counts you could try, for instance:

```
>>> {n: l.count(n) for n in [2, 5, 7]}
{2: 5, 5: 0, 7: 0}
```

If you want counts for *all* elements, I would suggest [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: This is going to be inefficient if the list is huge.

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.Counter` was introduced in py2.7, so for py 2.6 and earlier you can try something like this:

```
In [1]: l = [2L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 11L, 14L, 11L, 14L, 2L, 2L, 14L]

In [2]: dic={}

In [3]: for x in l:
   ...:     dic[x]=dic.get(x,0)+1
   ...:     

In [4]: dic
Out[4]: {2L: 5, 11L: 3, 14L: 6}
```

or use `defaultdict`(introduced in py2.5):

```
In [6]: from collections import defaultdict

In [7]: dic=defaultdict(int)

In [8]: for x in l:
    dic[x]+=1
   ...:     

In [9]: dic
Out[9]: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {2L: 5, 11L: 3, 14L: 6})
```